# Adding 2 sounds to 1 asset

Tags: unreal-4, sound, sound-effects, blueprints

I've got a sound looping from the start of the game, working exactly as I need it to. What I need is a second sound to alert the player that they have located the hidden object (the first sound is a locator sound to help them go in the right direction). My problem is that when I add the second sound to the object, there seems to be no change. Is there a way to add this second sound to go off when the player gets within the attenuation sphere? I don't want it to shut off the first sound though, just make the sound over it. That way if the player wanders away, they know where to go back to because the first sound will still be playing.

Answer (score 0):

Add an (another?) AudioComponent that can be triggered or toggled as needed.

Comment: I mentioned in my post that I did that, but it didn't work. I may have figured it out though. I believe it may be an issue with my blueprint. I'll update this if I fix it.

Comment: You said you'd added a second sound, not specifically a second AudioComponent. Please do post again if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Reference on sound attenuation in Unreal Engine
[Sound Attenuation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Audio/DistanceModelAttenuation)

[image: Sound attenuation sphere]

Comment: This answer would be better if it described what specific information from that link you want a reader to learn, or how to apply that information to solve OP's problem.